# not getting audio on a pjsip call out on android

Tags: android, pjsip

I have built the pjsua2 app and can get no audio on a dialed call.  I am new to pjsip and cannot tell from the log if I missed anything.  I do have a working demo using android's sip demo client that gives me hold music when i dial an extension on the asterisks switch.  But the use case for my project is to leverage the pjsip stack.

Can anyone see anything in the log that might give a clue what I am missing, this is a log of a single dial with no filters.  it looks to me like I just get hung up on.

[pjsip client log][1]

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1820e8x7Pa5vWDZmK3dSHMuS3FI75qqr-ynJZu-KzDk4/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turning the tcp to false on the client fixed the issue.  The log was useless. sorry!  Would love to know why